# Does attractiveness naturally change every few years in medieval settings?

Tags: society, sex

120 years ago being skinny was seen as unhealthy ugly and diseased, a sickening gross look to be skinny, women were actively shamed for that.

50 years ago dark skin was gross. then people started tanning for beauty, nowadays bright white skin is prefered again.

29 years ago skinny legs were preferable for women, now this it's all about big hips and and big thighs

9 years ago Asian people were seen as ugly both by Asian media and Western media, beauty standards where to look as american as possible. Now white people get facial bone surgeries to look asian and bleach their skin for that pale ghostly look.

8 Years ago big buts and big lips where gross, girls used to get bullied for those features, black women used to get surgeries to reduce their lips and hips... now black and white women get surgeries for bigger butts and bigger lips.

5 years ago feminine women were preferable, now short haired masculine tomboys are the big deal.

All of this can be verified with a few statistics on wikipedia, pornography websites, magazines and mass media advertising--- beauty magazines pushed different insecurities back then, ads pushed different beauty standards back then.

Is this cyclical change of human sexuality every few years a natural result of society and thus expected to happen in more primitive historical themes or does it only happen because of the modernization of culture?

is the nature of human sexuality to get bored of the same things and slowly develop attractions for the same things they were grossed out or is this to be expected only in modern and sci-fi stories? or maybe is human nature to change their sexuality as they grow up and get older and older? Or maybe human sexuality is as plasmable and easy to change as clay, so anyone can change the sexuality of another with a little propaganda?

Comment: I've lived through 9, 8, and 5 and observed what you call the result of 29, and everything you say is contrary to what I think I've seen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to worldbuilding Stack-Exchange! Know that we're more about dealing with creating worlds. However, it feels like you're asking more about the real-world than on how to make _your_ world. Can you explain what kind of world this question would help shaping (if that's indeed your goal)? It'll help us in return to give better answers. Also, have a look at the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't yet, if you want to know more about how WB:SE works :).

Comment: In victorian times they had a lot of fat shaming and fetishization of starvation. See Moulding the Female Body in Victorian Fairy Tales and Sensation Novels say.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Agreed, plus I've been through 29, and 50 as a kid.  SOME people may agree with any of those attractiveness factors, but not everyone does.  And WRT 120 years ago, note that there's a major difference between skinny because anorexic, diets, &c, and slender but fit because you work out a lot.  AFAIK, you had few if any athletic women 120 years ago.

Comment: Attractiveness seldom changes; it is mostly built-in into the male and female brain. Judge for yourself; do these women look attractive to you? [*Venus of Urbino*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_of_Urbino) (Titian, 1516); [Simonetta Vespucci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simonetta_Vespucci) (Piero di Cosimo, 1490); [*Venus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus) and [*Primavera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primavera_(Botticelli)) (Sandro Botticelli, about 1480). (Continued...)

Comment: (...Continued) What changes is *fashion*. This decade painters and photographers and clothes designers prefer to use thin models, next decade tall models, next decade well-built models. But what men find attractive rarely changes, and never changes all that much. For research purposes, look at the pictures in the *Playboy* magazine and tell whether you can discern a significant change in the attractiveness of women whose photographs men paid money to look at from 1953 onwards.

Comment: I believe the close-vote reasons are wrong. This could be answered if the OP specified how their culture worked and very much more context, it can be about worldbuilding and is opinion-based at present, but could be improved sufficiently to be answerable. VTC, needs details and clarity.

Comment: Are you asking about [physical attractiveness](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Physical_attractiveness), [ideals of beauty](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Feminine_beauty_ideal), or [sexuality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Human_sexuality)?  These are connected but not the same. Please edit your answer to clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: false, false, false, maybe, false, false,  "All of this can be verified with a few stat.."=triple false.   Sorry, but you are misleading yourself. Unless you limit your demographic to a **very** specific subculture, there will never be consensus on standards of beauty. By the time your focus is so narrow as to achieve consensus, you are looking at the opinion of well under one percent of humanity, and the "consensus" itself is a lie.

Comment: @AlexP: It's that personal taste thing again.  I don't find any of those really attractive, since they're all rather on the chubby/flabby side.  (Or is Urbino pregnant?)  Maybe if you put them on a good exercise program for a few months?  You might compare your paintings & Playboy models to say the results on a search for "Sports Illustrated swimsuit issue".

Answer (score 5):

### Trends are dictated by the influential

It really doesn't matter what age you look at, those who have the most influence and power tend to set the example in most fields, not only fashion and sexuality. Some of those examples tend to stick longer than others, eventually even becoming staples of culture long after those who set them are gone, or until another staple comes along to supplant it.

For example, wedding gowns weren't a thing until Queen Victoria's coronation, after that point it became a staple of our society because every woman should be treated as a queen on her wedding day and if you do not provide her with a fancy dress and a fancy feast and a fancy ceremony you will be shunned as a lousy husband. Further going into the subject of marriage, the wedding ring is also a relatively new thing, a marketing ploy invented by the De Beers Corporation that stuck in the mindset of America and spread through-out the world, because if you do not buy the love of your life an allegedly expensive piece of stone you do not love her in the first place. Sigh, the power of aggressive marketing.

As long as there are competitive corporations and individuals putting their mind at one-upping each-other, there will be potential for breakthroughs. Whenever those breakthroughs flop, we call them insane and laugh them out, but whenever one sticks people tend to mimic it for the sake of becoming influential, relevant, or "hip" themselves, or at least trying to be.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of boredom.

There seems to be a general trend in considering attractive what is scarce: for example in Southern Europe someone with blonde hair and blue eyes will be considered more attractive, while in Northern Europe dark hair and dark eyes do the trick, or consider the general appreciation toward red haired individuals. In times of general hunger, full bodies are a scarcity and thus attractive, as you can see in the Venuses painted during the Renaissance.

On top of this also the status of the economy seems to influence the tastes of the public: in years of economic prosperity slender bodies seems to be more attractive, while when the economy is down more full bodies are preferred. Take as a reference Twiggy in the 60s or Kate Moss in the 90s, and Kate Upton in the 2000s

Comment: Was the Renaissance a time of general hunger, especially for the class of people who'd be buying paintings?

Comment: There are many many Renaissance pictures of attractive women who are most definitely not fat... Do, for examples, [Botticelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandro_Botticelli)'s women look fat to you? [Gabrielle d'Estrées](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabrielle_d'Estrées_et_une_de_ses_sœurs)? [Simonetta Vespucci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simonetta_Vespucci)? Do you need more examples? (And fully-formed women have always been considered attractive and they still are.)

Comment: "There seems to be a general trend in considering attractive what is scarce"... and, biologically speaking, there *ought* to be. "Scarce" translates into "less common genes", the preservation of which improves genetic diversity. Of course, countering this, you don't want to perpetuate "bad" genes either, but at least between otherwise healthy individuals, it makes (biological) sense to favor diversity.

Comment: @AlexP, Botticelli's Venus, in the birth of Venus, has all but a flat tummy for the modern standards.

Comment: @AlexP journals and books are better representations of cultures than paintings

Comment: @AlexP: Botticelli is something of an outlier, I think.  But even when the women depicted are not on the chubby side, they are flabby.  See above comment about comparison to modern, physically fit women.

Comment: +1. The same could be said for "precious" metals. Gold would have had no practical application in medieval times, as it is soft and malleable. The main reason people want it is because it's rare.

Answer (score 3):

There are always both short term trends and long term trends. What you describe are the short term trends and those are driven by both advertising and media.

We are always interested in the new, exotic, and powerful. "Power is the ultimate aphrodisiac" - Henry Kissinger.

Long term trends are driven by economics, long term social trends, environment, and tribal beliefs. For example, caste systems have been part of the European tribes for over 3000 years with the belief of certain people being superior. Yet, environment can overrun that belief. White skin is a real disadvantage in a place like Sudan - high altitude and on the equator resulting in a very high UV load leading to a much higher cancer rate. Same way, the belief that the English were superior died quickly in the Southern American Colonies where new colonists from England died very fast while the African immigrants survived. Yet, the beliefs still drive much social and sexual policy.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about what society as a whole finds attractive, and the changeability of that given the absence of media or most media. You say Medieval--that's a wide span of time in a variety of places. But here's what's historically true.

- Trendsetters are still a thing. They are not movie stars. It's your world so figure that out but generally-- it's the rich, famous.
- Think Local. You can't generalize what's attractive or fashionable in all of Europe for instance, in a time period like this. Because there's less to no media, not only is it slower for a standard of beauty to spread, often it doesn't spread at all. Standards of beauty can be isolated to a community.
- Think by social strata or group. Take one large Medieval city. Or indeed one modern one. In any given large gathering of people, there are societal divisions. What's attractive to one group isn't attractive to another. This has been true for all of history. Even though the rich might follow a trend that is de riguer for them, doesn't mean that others outside their group might think it's ridiculous. What's pretty and fashionable at the goth club doesn't fly at the country club and vice versa.